# Account created inside another account

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts

Somehow in my friend's computer, someone managed to create an account inside another account. Ever since that happened, she hasn't been able to save documents or any kind of files for that matter inside her computer because it always tells her "*File or directory damaged or illegible*"

To give you an idea, there are two ways to access the very same folder:

```
C:\Users\Gilda\Desktop\fotos
```

and

```
C:\Users\Gilda\Desktop\Victoria Valdivia\Desktop\fotos
```

However, when you click the address bar on either, they both say: `C:\Users\Gilda\Desktop\fotos`

I really don't know what to do, and I can't find the answer anywhere else. I don't know if you can imagine what the problem is, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SuperUser.  The way things work here is that we reply in public, where everybody can see the answer, or not at all.  Thus, I have submitted an edit suggestion to remove your email address and the solicitation to contact you privately.

Comment: Oh sure, I didn't know that, thanks for the advice. I though it would be more convenient, instead of having dozens of comments explaining what the issue is. I guess it makes sense since this is a site to help other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to Accounts (in settings) select Family and other users.You should see Victoria Valdivia's account there.Just select her account and Remove.

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention it, but it seems like there's no way to access Victoria's account via the accounts folder. You can only get there via Gilda's account, although I'm unable to delete it from there. What's even weirder is that there's no way to access Gilda's account from the account folder either, so I have absolutely no idea how to access her account folder. I'd attach an image to show you, but I don't have her computer with me at the moment.

Comment: You sure you went to Settings >Accounts > Family and Other users  ?

Comment: Pretty sure I did, but it wouldn't hurt to check again tomorrow, I'll be sure to tell my friend to lend me her laptop tomorrow and I'll give you an update.